# How do we handle users that drag a meta discussion on to main?

Tags: discussion

Examples would include rehashing personal perspective about an issue brought up on meta on main or posting paragraph long comments that offer no forward movement to the question at hand.

Is this considered a positive way to counter being disagreed with on meta, just nonsensical stupidity, or counterproductive problematic behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<sub>**Edit:** This answer has evolved as I've found out its background. Still essentially the same answer, with a note on comments.</sub>

If there is off-topic nonsense within a **question** or **answer**, feel free to edit it out. Leave an explanation in your edit message, or leave a comment. If there's any strife or abuse as feedback, or the edit just gets rolled back, **kick it up to moderators immediately**.

**Comments** are generally used around the site for meta purposes. Be that clarifying a question, suggesting edits or suggesting how to *deal* with it. This is what they're for. If you disagree with the comment, tread carefully. You can reply but again, catch the wrong person on the wrong day and you're having a full-on argument. If things start bending that way, phone in the moderators and we can stand around moderating stuff.

If you feel something is attempting to derail a question (be this an edit, a comment, or whatever), don't sit there and argue with the user. **90% of times this will make things much worse.** Flag it and kick it up to your moderators.

We're fairly good at extinguishing things before they go too far.

Answer (score 3):

It's negative and counter-productive.  We should kill it with fire.

Answer (score 0):

It's pointless, but mostly benign.

Answer (score -4):

It's a great idea, I don't know why we have meta anyway.

Comment: You really have lost me now.  What are you trying to say?

Comment: meta voting. He obviously doesn't mean that. :)

Comment: don't you wish we could down vote in presidential, gubernatorial, local elections? _The results are in! President Obama beats out Romney -45,000,545 to -55,003,343!_